# Setting a jQuery slider maximum value to unlimited?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you set a jQuery slider to have a maximum value of 10,000 - but then if moved at all to the left it scales as though it was a slider of between 1-50 (if they move it to the right it returns to the very high value).

So it would be something like:

min: 0,
 max: 50,
 secondmax: 10000, (<- this is what I need to figure out).
 values: [0, 50, 10000],

We have a filter by distance slider on our job board and want it, by default to be unlimited - and then if the user moves the slider left it should scale between reasonable values (1-50).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably easier to handle this outside of the slider itself, for example:

You could make the slider something like 1-51. In your code for the distance filter detect a value >50 and make it perform the unlimited distance filtering (possibly just by replacing the value of 51, with 10,000)

Answer (score 4):

In the slide: function(e, ui){...} you could detect what the current value is (ui.value) and if ui.value > max then change the max. It would look something like this:

```
var $mySlider = $('#mySlider');
$mySlider.slider({
   slide: function(e, ui){
      var currMax = $mySlider.slider('option', 'max');
      if (ui.value > currMax) {
         $mySlider.slider('option', 'max', currMax++)
      }
   }
});
```

Or like this:

```
var $mySlider = $('#mySlider');
$mySlider.slider({
   slide: function(e, ui){
      var currMin = $mySlider.slider('option', 'min');
      var currMax = $mySlider.slider('option', 'max');
      if (ui.value >= currMax) {
         $mySlider.slider('option', 'min', currMin++);
         $mySlider.slider('option', 'max', currMax++);
      } else if (ui.value <= currMin){
         $mySlider.slider('option', 'min', currMin--);
         $mySlider.slider('option', 'max', currMax--);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Lovely solution. Just pointing for the increase/decrease on currMin and currMax the ++ and -- operators should go infront of the variables to make the change effective before passing the value as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more intuitive to your users to use a normal slider and an 'Unlimited' checkbox.

Comment: I had this by user testing showed it was confusing - and people didn't really understand.  The problem is that, by default, filtering by distance is turned off.  Hiding the Slider and showing it when the checkbox ([ ] filter by distance) was checked was too visually subtle (people missed the checkbox) and having it visible but not active until the checkbox was checked was too confusing (people were wondering why it wasn't filtering by distance)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not? If you wanted to do this, you could run a function every time the slider changes. In this function, you can check the value of the current position. If it's less than 50, change the slider as you need. If it's above 50, same.